# Browsing to Subversion repository location indicated in Apache conf file

Tags: svn, apache2, windows-vista, dynamic-ip

I have Subversion 1.6.6 and Apache 2.2.14 installed and working.

I have made the following changes to the Apache httpd.conf file:

#Uncommented by me for Subversion installation

LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so

LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so

#Added by me for subversion installation

LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so

LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so

< Location /svn>

DAV svn

SVNPath C:\Users\RED\Repositories

< /Location>

...When I navigate to localhost Apache is working properly, but if I try to go to localhost/svn the browser just hangs waiting for a response from the server.

What is supposed to happen here? Does it have to do with the fact that I'm behind a wireless router on a dynamic IP address (although I can access localhost no problem so...)? As you can see I'm on windows (Vista)

Answer (score 1):

## Aha!

I figured out one of my problems. My directory C:\Users\RED\Repositories is actually the SVNParentPath, not the SVNPath.

So I changed the httpd.conf file variable SVNPath to SVNParentPath and now when I browse to localhost/svn I get a 403 Forbidden response instead of hanging...so now I need to fix my permissions (so on to more research).

Comment: Aha again, I found out that I can access localhost/svn/MyRepo but I can't access localhost/svn. according to this forum 

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-subversion-with-web-access-on-ubuntu/ 

PhyloGenesis had the same issue and it has to do with setting up the parent and repository directories correctly.

I guess I'm answering my own questions as I go. oh well.